# Android - Loading fragment implementation

Tags: android, android-fragments, loading

I'd like to start my app and show the main screen instantly. Half of the info on the screen will be loaded form local storage and the other half will be from a web service. Each of these will be on two different fragments. I'd like to display a loading indeterminate progress bar while the data is being fetch from the webservice, similar to how the Google Play Store loads it's app date as shown below by the two states below:

[image: State 1 & State 2 (Google Play Store)]

My thoughts on implementing it are as follows:

Load the fragment in with the progress bar & the normal screen (hidden) in one layout. Once the data from the web service has been collected, populate the normal screen, then hide the view group containing the progress bar and show the viewgroup with the data.

Is this best practice? Are the better ways to do it than this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes your approach is better one and is widely used to show this kind of loading in the android application. You need to have two view, loading and web service data. when user first land on the page you will show loading data, Web service view will be hidden/gone and only loading will be shown. once loading is done hide/gone loading view and show normal web service data.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it yourself but you can also use a simple library called [**ProgressFragment**](http://johnkil.github.io/Android-ProgressFragment/)
avalaible on github