# loading progress in view pager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i am using view pager which has three fragment loading data from api. to show loading i have a utility class for showing playStore like loading. i.e

```
public class SpinnerFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int SPINNER_WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int SPINNER_HEIGHT = 100;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(container.getContext());
        if (container instanceof FrameLayout) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                    new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(SPINNER_WIDTH, SPINNER_HEIGHT, Gravity.CENTER);
            progressBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        return progressBar;
    }
}
```

i am using it any single fragment which is switching dynamically with frame layout in navigationview with fragment as usual. in which loading is working.

but in case i have fragment with viewpager that have three fragment as i said. so how can i use frame layout with pager to show loading.

to use above SpinnerFragment i add it by

```
//where content_frame is frame layout inside navigationView
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, spinnerFragment).commit();
```

and remove it by

```
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(spinnerFragment).commit();
```

now in view pager

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

how can i use frame_layout to add or remove fragment ?

Comment: oh... as i can understand you want to show loading all in three fragments while data is getting fetched from the server ?

Comment: of course. but i don't want to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855020/android-loading-fragment-implementation library.

Comment: better solution add your loading view inside each of three fragments and then play with them as hide or show against rest of the views.

Comment: yeah but i want better approach if there is any. a util solution that i can use anywhere in any fragment.

Comment: wt ever i have suggested is easiest way to do it. it will complex add or remove views

Comment: i didn't think about it. adding removing view will be complex and it will take resource. thanks.

Comment: again please have look at this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138213/progressdialog-in-wrong-tab/37141493#37141493

Comment: thanks again for telling me that issue. i am handling it using `
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && !isApiCalled) {
       // api call
            isApiCalled = true;
        }
    }` so each api call fire only once. so it is good for further development as it is. because all fragment inside view pager using api.